# Arduino IDE crashes before it opens on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: arduino

I currently installed Arduino 1.8.6 in Ubuntu 16.04, but it crashes before it opens. It worked fine for 2 days, and now it crashes. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you edit your question and post the exact errors you get when it crashes?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu sir, please edit your queston and explain me what the steps you do and what the output log of your crash error sir

Comment: Arduino IDE crashes without showing any errors. I am new to Ubuntu and i somehow managed to find the syslog from /var/log/syslog

Comment: Sep 13 18:16:55 anjish-HP-Pavilion-11-notebook org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1067]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2171): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application:///home/anjish/Desktop/arduino-arduinoide.desktop
Sep 13 18:17:01 anjish-HP-Pavilion-11-notebook CRON[12312]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 13 18:17:33 anjish-HP-Pavilion-11-notebook gnome-session[1214]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:

Comment: @N0rbert VTLO because maybe Arduino IDE is stuck because arduino-mhall119 snap package got stuck halfway through the update while it was being refreshed and it needs to be rolled back to the cached previous version to get it unstuck.